# Why does div with ng-if prevent its sibling from running Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have just spent hours trying to discover why the Angular in one div suddenly stopped working. I finally tracked it down to a sibling div which has an `ng-if="someVar"`. Currently `someVar` is true and the div displays and functions properly, including some `ng-mouseover`s, some `ng-click`s and plenty of live updating scope `{{variables}}`.

However for some reason having this ng-if there causes its sibling's functions to completely stop functioning. `{{otherVars}}` just remain completely static and all `ng-mouseover`s and `ng-click`s just completely stop doing anything. Why the heck is this happening??

This is a compacted version of my code:

```
<div class="first-div" ng-if="!showFAQ">
    <p class="title">
        <span ng-mouseover="message = messages.default; defaultHover = true" ng-mouseleave="defaultHover = false">{{defaultHover}}</span>
    </p>
    <span class="enter-button-inner" ng-mouseover="defaultHover = true; message = messages.enterButton" ng-mouseleave="defaultHover = false" ng-click="enterApp()">
        Click here to start
    </span>
</div>
<div class=" second-div show-message-{{defaultHover}}">
    {{message}}
</div>
```

All the Angular directives and functions in the `first-div` work perfectly, whereas all the code in the `second-div` simply doesn't work at all.

Why is this?

Comment: I had the same problem. I solve it by changing in-if to ng-show. This is not perfect solution because ng-show works slightly different then ng-if but it works

Comment: Any errors on the browser Javascript console? There's certainly nothing inherently in `ng-If` that stops sibling  code from working. Also watch out for the perils of binding to primitives: http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/ - which is what you do.

Comment: No, nothing whatsoever in the console. Which makes it all the more frustrating and ridiculous. And all my other code works fine, regardless of whether they're bound to primitives. It is literally only this one sibling div which has gone dead.

Answer (score 3):

**Build Understanding**:

1. `ng-if` will remove elements from DOM. This means that all your handlers or anything else attached to those elements will be lost. For example, if you bound a click handler to one of child elements, when `ng-if` evaluates to false, that element will be removed from DOM and your click handler will not work any more, even after `ng-if` later evaluates to true and displays the element. You will need to reattach the handler.
2. `ng-show/ng-hide` does not remove the elements from DOM. It uses CSS styles to hide/show elements (note: you might need to add your own classes). This way your handlers that were attached to children will not be lost.
3. `ng-if` creates a child scope while `ng-show/ng-hide` does not

Comment: Ok I understand but all my code inside of the `first-div` still works absolutely perfectly, regardless of its detachment and reattachment to the DOM. Why is this `ng-if` affecting the working of an entirely separate sibling??

Comment: Could you pleae setup fiddle/bin or plnkr ? I can see and fix for you happily :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might want to use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) instead.

The difference with [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) is that ngIf completely removes your element from the DOM, where ngShow just hides it. When ng-if evaluates to true again, it creates a clone of your element and adds it back to the DOM.

Comment: I know of ng-show but firstly it does work differently than ng-if and secondly more importantly I want to understand why angular works in such a stupid manner

Comment: You might want to wait for an answer from someone with more experience than me then, I'm not that much familiar with ngIf I wouldn't want to give you a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your setting scope variables in the `<div>` is failing (probably due to primitives in `ng-if's scope).

```
<div class="first-div" ng-if="!model.showFAQ">
    <p class="title">
        <span ng-mouseover="hoverHndl(true, messages.default)" 
            ng-mouseleave="hoverHndl(false)">Hover me!: {{defaultHover}}
        </span>
    </p>
    <span class="enter-button-inner" 
        ng-mouseover="hoverHndl(true, messages.enterButton)" 
        ng-mouseleave="hoverHndl(false)" 
        ng-click="enterApp()">
        Click here to start
    </span>
</div>
<div class=" second-div show-message-{{defaultHover}}">
    message: {{message}}
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$scope.showFAQ = true;
$scope.messages = {
  default: "defaulMsg",
  enterButton: "enterButton"
};

$scope.message = 'initialMsg';

$scope.hoverHndl = function(hover, message) {
  $scope.defaultHover = hover;
  $scope.message = message;            
};
```

See it is working here if you do the assignment in a function: https://jsbin.com/lahoyevuqo/1/edit?html,js,output